# how to make a restAPI call to laravel using react

Tags: laravel, api, reactjs, routes

Currently, my `restAPI` and my App are both hosted on `XAMPP`. My `restAPI` url is `laravel.dev`.

My `POST` route looks as so...

```
Route::post('/content', 'Test@save');
```

and my Controller...

```
class Test extends Controller
{
    public function save() 
    {
        return "here";
    }
}
```

Pretty simple, but now I want to make a `POST` request to this route from my App. I am trying to that using react's `fetch`, but I do not know what URL to put since my attempt does not work...

```
fetch('laravel.dev', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            firstParam: 'yourValue',
            secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
        })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
    });
```

I don't care about passing anything to the route, I just want a successful call to the `restAPI` server. Right now I'm getting...

```
POST http://localhost/App/src/laravel.dev 404 (Not Found)
```

That is also the wrong path as well, as `/App` is my app and I am trying to call the `restAPI` server.

What do I need to change to make a successful call?

Comment: what's the actual full url for your endpoint? put that as the first argument to `fetch` (which btw is not a react thing)

Comment: @azium what do you mean by endpoint? Currently my laravel folder is in `localhost/laravel`, but do I need to point the URL to the actual `routes.php` file?

Comment: I mean the full url of the post request.. something like `http://localhost:<port>/content` . it might just need to be `/content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` needs a protocol. Right now it tries to request a "local" resource. Also, add your endpoint:

```
fetch('http://laravel.dev/content', {
  // ...
});
```